# Error SQL syntax in a trigger, MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, insert

I receive this message "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6" but can not figure out what is wrong.

(position and points are MEDIUMINT, they are not primary key neither unique)

Anyone?

```
CREATE TRIGGER pointsAssigns
before INSERT ON MyTable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.position>6 THEN
    set NEW.points=5;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Add an `END;` as the last line.Also do you use a DELIMITER?

Comment: I tried both but does not work..The error should be in the '5'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mihai mentioned either add closing `END` and change the `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pointsAssigns
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.position > 6 THEN
    SET NEW.points = 5;
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15eaf/1)** demo

or make it one-line trigger and then you don't need neither `BEGIN...END` block nor changing the `DELIMITER`

```
CREATE TRIGGER pointsAssigns
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.points = IF(NEW.position > 6, 5, NEW.points);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/220e6/1)** demo

Comment: I have tried it before, but only NOW it seems to work..THNAK YOU